# Why is Naruto hated in the beginning?

Tags: naruto

Why is Naruto hated so much when the village had so many Jinchurikis in the past? Didn't they know the risks of having a tailed beast so close by?

Comment: My memory is vague but wasn't there an agreement that nobody mentions to Naruto that his body is being used as the fox's vessel? That might have been a factor in people not talking to him completely.

Comment: Hey welcome to A&M. How far are you already in the series? This will be explained fairly well throughout the series, and explanations might very well spoil you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, he was mainly hated because Kyubi attacked the village and caused death of the 4th Hokage.

Because he was its vessel, the hate of the villagers for Kyubi has been transfered to Naruto himself.

Answer (score 2):

First off all, they didn't hate him, but rather, they were afraid of him. This is because he had half of Kyubi seal into [him](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=sad+naruto+childhood).

---

Dont forget one fact, that the Kyubi was used in two battles which much influence future of the village. He was summoned by Madara during his fight with [Hashirama](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJKVZyTZ17A), and was released during the birth of Naruto by [Obito](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1rLJW_nEfI). This was actually one of the most devestating attacks on Konoha so far. Many people died in this fight, for example, Iruka´s parents, and The Hokage Minato. This event makes people of Konoha only see a symbol of destruction, death.

---

Answer (score 0):

I don't think he was hated per se, but I believe that they were afraid of him because he was being used as a vessel and they knew that. Plus, it could have been because he was just a kid without parents and living alone.